# On checkout, is it possible to include "Visa Checkout", "Amex Checkout", Mastercard Securecode + Paypal?

Tags: security, checkout, payment, privacy

My goal is to create a signup screen that allows the easiest and most secure way to pay for a product.

In most cases, I can improve the security and reduce payment disputes by using brand specific sign in flows. (Visa/Mastercard/Amex)

However, when it comes to ease of use, some people love Paypal, Apple Pay, or Google Pay.

My goal is to create a flow that allows for both flexibility and security. Some of the proposed currencies include

Brand specific:

- Amex [Checkout](https://www.americanexpress.com/us/content/express-checkout/index.html)
- Mastercard [SecurePay](https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/consumers/features-benefits/securecode.html)
- Bitcoin / AltCoin

Aggregate, supports many different payment types above

- Paypal
- Google Pay
- Apple Pay [on the web](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/)
- [Venmo](http://blog.venmo.com/hf2t3h4x98p5e13z82pl8j66ngcmry/paying-apps-with-venmo)

Proposed design:

1. Screen 1 asks what kind of card are you using (Visa/Master/Amex/Bitcoin)
2. Based on the selection above, then present the user with a place to type a card number in.  Below that include a sign in for a Visa/Paypal/Google Pay.
3. If the machine happens to be OSX sierra, then add the Apple Pay button. It will automatically remain hidden if Apple pay isn't set up.

**Question**

Is this a good payment flow? What can be improved?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're over complicating things. If users already have a preferred payment method, then **the credit card step is not needed at all** (not to mention they might use services that are funded by different methods than credit card. For example: Paypal users may fund with wire transfers, have credit from payments, etc).

In short, it's as easy as this: Make your users select a service, like this:

> **How would you like to pay?**
>
> -> Paypal
>
> -> Google Pay
>
> -> Apple Pay on the web
>
> -> Venmo

and from there, users will be able to select the credit card (if needed)